# Find array index inside another array

Tags: python, numpy

Lets say i have two numpy arrays or lists example

```
a = ['P', 'P' ,'Q', 'Q','P' ,'P','Q', 'Q']
b = ['Q', 'Q','P' ,'P']
```

and the result that i expect would be that it starts at

```
start = 2
end = 6
```

Comment: `'|'.join(a).split('|'.join(b))[0].count('|')`

Comment: @splash58 thank you for your help, based on your solution i was able to edit it and fix my problem, if you want you can answer it and i will you as the one who solved it

Answer (score 2):

Example below without converting to string

```py
a = ['P', 'P' ,'Q', 'Q','P' ,'P','Q', 'Q']
b = ['Q', 'Q','P' ,'P']

for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i:i+len(b)] == b:
        print i,i+len(b)
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easiest, if you convert the lists to a string:

```
a1 = ''.join(a)
b1 = ''.join(b)
```

then you can use the `str.find()` function that  returns the lowest index of the substring if it is found in given string. If its is not found then it returns -1.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for you help, based on commentary discussion i was able to find this

```
a = ['P', 'P' ,'Q', 'Q','P' ,'P','Q', 'Q']
b = ['Q', 'Q','P' ,'P']

start = '|'.join(a).split('|'.join(b))[0].count('|')
end  = start + len(b)

if start == len(a)-1:
    print('the subset wasnt found')
else:
    print('the subset was found, start: ', start, 'end: ',end)
```